# OWASP Zed Attack Proxy Setup Error, Connection Reset

Tags: security, firefox, owasp, zap

I am trying to set up Zed Attack Proxy with Firefox to scan my web application. For some reason the following the steps in their guide didn't work: https://youtu.be/Xp_PBH7wjiw

Firefox keeps giving a "The connection was reset" error. It's not just for my website though, I can't even open google.com without it giving the connection was reset error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this FAQ https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQhelp

Can you proxy http traffic, ie is it just https traffic that fails?
Have you imported the ZAP root certificate?
Are there any errors in the zap.log file?

Cheers,

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)

Comment: Hey Simon, thanks for the response. I am not able to proxy any traffic, not even http. I have imported the ZAP root certificate into Firefox and I see no errors in the zap.log file.

Comment: And you're using the latest version of Firefox and ZAP?
Can you email me a screenshot of your browser proxy configuration?
Email - my username at gmail.com